# Bootstrap carousel items snapping into place and changing height of parent div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, carousel

I've made a bootstrap carousel with items each containing three columns.

As the slide transition ends, the items snap into place and very briefly change the height of the parent div.

I've spent all day trying to find a solution but can't see anything! I'm assuming it is something to do with padding/margins as the slide happens. I've tried forcing the items to have no padding or margins but no luck.

Does anyone know anything about this issue? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

The link to the page with the issue is [here](http://elisweb.co.uk/martin/test.html)

And the code itself:

```css
.tourenEvents {
  background: #2a2a2a;
}
.tourenEvents .tourenEventsInner {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
.tourenEvents .tourenEventsInner .carousel .item .carouselBlock {
  margin: 0 !important; /* This was one of the attempts to fix the issue */
}
.tourenEvents .tourenEventsInner .carousel .item .carouselBlock img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* == Carousel Control styles - I don't think the issue comes from here but I'm posting it just incase == */
#tourenCarousel .carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}
#tourenCarousel .carousel-control {
  background-image: none !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 15vh;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #2a2a2a;
  text-shadow: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #tourenCarousel .carousel-control {
    padding-top: 10vh;
  }
}
#tourenCarousel .carousel-control:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#tourenCarousel .carousel-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
#tourenCarousel .left {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
#tourenCarousel .right {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="tourenEvents col-sm-12">
      
        <div class="tourenEventsInner col-lg-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
            <h3 class="text-center">Check out our events</h3>
            <!-- div:tourenCarousel is the carousel of events -->
            <div id="tourenCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#tourenCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#tourenCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#tourenCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active">
                      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                          <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                              <a href='#'><img src="images/tourentipps/events1.png" alt="Events 1"></a>
                              <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                              <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                              <a href='#'><img  src="images/tourentipps/events2.png" alt="Events 2"></a>
                              <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                              <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                              <a href='#'><img  src="images/tourentipps/events3.png" alt="Events 3"></a>
                              <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                              <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                   <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                        <a href='#'><img class="img-responsive" src="images/tourentipps/events2.png" alt="Events 2"></a>
                        <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                        <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                       <a href='#'><img class="img-responsive" src="images/tourentipps/events3.png" alt="Events 3"></a>
                        <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                        <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                       <a href='#'><img class="img-responsive" src="images/tourentipps/events1.png" alt="Events 1"></a>
                       <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                       <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                       <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                    <a href='#'><img class="img-responsive" src="images/tourentipps/events3.png" alt="Events 3"></a>
                    <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                    <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
               </div>
               <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                   <a href='#'><img class="img-responsive" src="images/tourentipps/events1.png" alt="Events 1"></a>
                    <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                    <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
               </div>
               <div class="carouselBlock col-lg-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                   <a href='#'><img class="img-responsive" src="images/tourentipps/events2.png" alt="Events 2"></a>
                    <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                    <p class="lightPara">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#tourenCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#tourenCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I never liked bootstrap's carousel for this reason, and was never able to figure out how to fix your issue. I would recommend using Slick Slider: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Just had a look at that now, looks great! Thanks very much for the advice Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:100%` on `.tourenEvents .tourenEventsInner .carousel .item .carouselBlock img`

you are resizing width on active class.

Comment: Wow! Okay, so that (mostly) fixed the issue. The div no longer changes height but the item still snaps into place which is not such a big deal. However, now the images don't work so well as I can't specify the width within their column? How would I keep the fix you said but still be able to define the image width?

Comment: looks like its this too classes `#tourenCarousel .left {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
#tourenCarousel .right {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
`